# Install 10.6, 10.7 and 10.8 on same machine

Tags: macos, boot, osx-snow-leopard, osx-lion, osx-mountain-lion

I have a MacBookPro with 10.6 running on it. I am using it as a base machine for development.

I want to understand how can I install 10.6, 10.7 and 10.8 on same machine, so that I can continue to develop in different environment with same machine.

I know that on new Machines we buy from apple comes preinstalled with 10.8 and we cannot install 10.6 as snow leopard kernel does not support new hardware. But reverse is not true. I can install 10.7 and 10.8 on machine I have.

I have 10.7 Recovery Disk and 10.6 disk. I can buy 10.8 from store.

Can some one help understand what steps do I need to follow to accomplish Installation of 10.6, 10.7 and 10.8 on same machine?

Answer (score 2):

Partition your HardDrive and install each system on a separate partition. You will not be able to use more than one system at a time, but you have three systems on one box.

Using Virtualization will not help much as it is not easily possible to install a Client-system out of the box. Apple supports only installation of a server system in a virtualized environment. There are manuals to install client-systems, but it's really tricky.

Sometimes it *is* possible to install snow-leopard on a new machine via cloning it from an older machine. But it depends on the hardware whether it then starts with the old system or not. There are machines though that prohibit installing 10.6 from the install-disc but start from a cloned 10.6 system.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Parallels](http://www.parallels.com/) or [Vmware Fusion](http://www.vmware.com/products/fusion/overview.html) to do this.  Both support OS X as a guest OS.